# adding multiple proxy in subversion clients

Tags: svn

Is there any way to add multiple proxy in subversion client configuration.
Lets say, I have a svn remote https://svn.example1.net which is to be accessed with proxy1 and another svn remote which can be accessed with proxy2. 
How can we add 2  proxies wrt to the remote url. 
Is there any way to add a common proxy and a special proxy for a specific svn url ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can configure different proxies for different servers. Please, read the documentation: [SVNBook | Runtime Configuration Area](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.confarea.html#svn.advanced.confarea.opts.servers).

First, you need to configure groups in the `servers` file. Groups define what proxy server will be used depending on the server URL. Next, you need to add proxy settings to these groups. Here is an example:

```
[groups]
server1 = svn.example1.com
server2 = svn.anotherdomain.com

[server1]
http-proxy-host = proxy1.domain-name.com
http-proxy-port = 80
http-proxy-username = MyUsername1
http-proxy-password = MyPassword1

[server2]
http-proxy-host = proxy2.domain-name.com
http-proxy-port = 8443
http-proxy-username = MyUsername2
http-proxy-password = MyPassword2
```